# MapKit overlays to add floor plans to map

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkoverlay, mktileoverlay

I am trying to add an overlay to iOS MapKit in order to show floor plans. However, I am unsure about the best way of doing this. If I add the floor plans by using an MKOverlay, will the floor plans be loaded lazily or do I need to find out which part of the map is being displayed and update overlays thereafter? I also looked at using MKTileOverlay, as it is using lazy loading, but I have the impression that it should be used for completely covering of the map and not only to add to the existing one. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right `MKTileOverlay` can cover whole map with tiles and Yes it is using lazy loading.

Use `MKOverlay` if you are not willing to replace native look and fill of map. You can also achieve lazy loading for `MKOverlay` too.

**Note:** `MKTileOverlay` will not remove your already existing `MKAnnotations` and `MKOverlay`.

Comment: Thank you. Is lazy loading used automatically for MKOverlay, or do I need to configure it in a special way? Also, should my overlays be added to one MKOverlayView, or separate MKOverlayView per overlay?

Comment: For `MKOverlay` create block or background thread for lazy loading and DO NOT need to create separate, All overlays will be manage on same `MKOverlayView`.

Answer (score 0):

`MKOverlay` is a protocol, not a class. You want `MKTileOverlay` as of iOS 7. Things are lazy loaded according to what portion of the map is currently shown.

You might find this useful as a reference on how the tiles are numbered and organized:

https://www.mapbox.com/foundations/how-web-maps-work/

As for covering Apple's map, this will happen by default, but you can also adjust the `MKOverlayLevel` used to place it between Apple's base map and labels layer, or you can use `canReplaceMapContent = YES` if you want to disable Apple's maps entirely.